# C++: constructors,inheritance, and initialization

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, initialization

I am just beginning to learn C++, and am a little confused by the interplay of instantiation, constructor declaration, and inheritance... I think I'm beginning to wrap my head around everything, but I'd like to make sure I've conceptualized things correctly. I've provided a a class and a list of what I *think* is going on:

```
class Classy{
private:
    int foo1;
    int foo2;
public:
    //constructor 1
    Classy() { foo1 = 0; foo2 = 0; }
    //constructor 2
    Classy(int bar1) : foo1(bar1), foo2(0) {}
    //constructor 3
    Classy(int bar1, int bar2) : foo1(bar1) { foo2 = bar2; }
};
```

- Constructor 1 does things the way I'm used to; a call to the constructor sets the foo properties via assignment.
- Constructor 2 uses inherited constructors from the int class.
- Constructor 3 is a combination of the above.

Inherited constructors can also be from a class' parent - for example:

```
Child(args) : Parent(args) { ...extras }
```

which more or less acts like `Child(args) { super(args); ...extras }` in the languages I'm more familiar with. If we additionally have complex properties (say prop1 is a complex classes - a string or something), then we can instantiate them with their constructors through something like this:

```
Child(args) : Parent(args), prop1(args) { ...extras }
```

Does that sum everything up properly? Are there any aspects that I'm missing, or useful elaborations on what I've stated?

Comment: The other languages you're familiar with probably always have default initialization available for member variables... for example, a `null` reference.  In C++ objects can be contained by value, and default initialization doesn't always make sense.

Comment: You have the right understanding although not always the right terminology; `int` is not a class, nor does it have constructors. But `foo1(bar1) means that `bar1` is used as the *initializer* for `foo1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're abusing the term *inherited*.

Those are subobject constructors, and subobjects include both member variables and base class subobjects.  The word *inheritance* only goes with base class subobjects.  The corresponding word for member subobjects is *composition*.

Using the *ctor-initializer* list is better than assignment inside the constructor body for a couple reasons:

- It can be used for types that have no default constructor.
- It can be used for types that can't be assigned, such as references and const member variables.
- It is more efficient, because it doesn't require first creating state with the default constructor that simply gets replaced.

You can also use functions and arbitrary expressions when building the parameter lists for the subobject constructors -- they don't have to simply be the arguments passed to your constructor.

If you use an empty pair of parentheses, you'll get *value-initialization* of a sub-object, instead of *default initialization*.  If there's a default constructor, these are the same.  Otherwise, value initialization will get your subobject zeroed, while default initialization will leave an indeterminate, possibly illegal state.

In C++11, you often want to use the universal initializer syntax with `{}` instead of `()` when invoking subobject constructors.

Here's an example where these syntaxes are useful:

```
class Classy
{
  // private is the default access specifier for classes
    int bar[100];
    const std::array<int, 100> baz;
    static std::array<int, 100> make_array(int x)
    {
        std::array<int, 100> retval;
        for( int i = 0; i < 100; ++i )
            retval[i] = i * x;
        return retval;
    }
public:
    //constructor 1
    Classy() : bar{}, baz{} {}
    //constructor 2
    Classy(int bar1) : bar{}, baz{make_array(bar1)} {}
};
```

Comment: Noted - I'm not used to so-called subobjects having constructors that can be called in the same location as inherited constructors... Perhaps that's where I'm getting confused? Food for thought. What is a ctor-initializer?

Comment: @Nate: The *ctor-initializer* list is everything between the `:` and the opening `{` of the constructor body.

Comment: Understood. Could you include a code example for the portion of your answer on value initialization vs. default initialization? Also: why is uniform initialization ('{}') preferred over constructor initialization ('()')?

Comment: @Nate: Here's your example.  Uniform initialization works on aggregates (arrays, structs) that don't actually have a constructor.

Comment: Understood! Thanks for the explanation - terminology seems to be my biggest issue, and most of the tutorials I've found seem to think I already know it.